# Let's Encrypt SSL in Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I try to search it on the internet but found nothing. I want to install Let's Encrypt SSL cert via bash script. I will run below command in the bash script:

```
certbot --nginx -d $sitename -d www.$sitename
```

and it will prompt below questions,

- enter **e-mail** address (used for......):
- Please read terms of....... (**A**)gree/(**C**)ancel:
- (**Y**)es/(**N**)o:

How can I automate above prompts in bash script?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for its commandline options? https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-commands

Comment: Automating prompts is a fragile, last-ditch approach and should only be used when a program doesn't provide programmatic interfaces -- certainly not the case here.

Comment: @jhnc yes friend, I read it but I didn't understand. Because I'm very noob about bash.

Comment: Hi @Cyrus thank you for great answer. I can't vote for your answers. System doesn't allow it. But I already accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sitename="example.com"
certbot --nginx -d "$sitename" -d "www.$sitename" -m foo@example.com --agree-tos -n
```

---

See: `certbot --help`